# How to pretty-print SHOW CREATE VIEW output in MySQL CLI?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

You can run `SHOW CREATE VIEW someview;` to see the view definition. However, MySQL returns the definition without line breaks making it very hard to read.

Doing `SHOW CREATE VIEW someview \G` is slightly better as it doesn't result in multiple lines of table borders filling up the screen (`--------------`)

Is there a way to print the view definition more readable, with line breaks?

Comment: Did you try this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/170610/how-to-retrieve-the-query-i-used-to-create-a-view

Comment: @clinomaniac Yes, it shows the view definition but is barely readable. Please read the question..